# I can't set my initial data from database in my redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await

I've change my code to this but not working yet...
this give me a promise, But the data arrives late (asynchronous)

```
import { getItems } from '../services/itemService';

function delay() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(42);
        }, 1000);
    });
}

const getAllItems = async () => {
    try {
        var { data } = await getItems();
        await delay();
        return data.map(obj => ({ ...obj, value: 0 }));
    } catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
};

const states = getAllItems();
const defaultState = states.then(value => {
    console.log(value);
    return value;
});

console.log(defaultState);
export default defaultState;
```

Comment: `getAllItems` returns a `promise` so you will have to use `await`  here.

`const states = await getAllItems();`

This line is at the top level so you can not use `await ` here. 
try to use `then` approach or `IIFE` approach to use `await ` at top level.

What is the use of `delay` function here?

Comment: like this?`const defaultState = (async function() {
    let states = await getAllItems();
    console.log(states);
})().then(value => {
    console.log(value);
    return value;
});` @Usama Tahir

Comment: yes.
Please confirm this solution and let me know as well. thanks